# Mutate dataframe(True/False) when string contain

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this,

| sample | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| My car is black | is black |
| My car is red | are red |
| My car is yellow | yellow |
| My car is green | black |

and I want to check if column 1's data is included in column sample.

Expected df:

| sample | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My car is black | is black | True |
| My car is red | are red | False |
| My car is yellow | yellow | True |
| My car is green | black | False |

I tried to create this with for loop function, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `str_detect` which is vectorized over string and pattern.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- df %>% mutate(X2 = str_detect(sample, X1))
df

#            sample       X1    X2
#1  My car is black is black  TRUE
#2    My car is red  are red FALSE
#3 My car is yellow   yellow  TRUE
#4  My car is green    black FALSE
```

---

In base R, you can use `Vectorize` `grepl`.

```
df$X2 <- Vectorize(grepl)(df$X1, df$sample)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grepl`

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(X2 = grepl(X1,sample))

  sample           X1       X2   
  <chr>            <chr>    <lgl>
1 My car is black  is black TRUE 
2 My car is red    are red  FALSE
3 My car is yellow yellow   TRUE 
4 My car is green  black    FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(data.table)
library(stirngr)
setDT(df)[, X2 := str_detect(sample, X1)]
```